# Increase Efficiency in Zip Reader in PHP

Tags: php, zip, mp3, unzip

I have some php code that reads the first file of a remote zip file containing mp3s. I know that in the zip file format, each file has a compressed size in its header. However, when I use fread to that number after going through the header, it only goes to about 5454 characters. I have made a fix, but it is very slow.

```
$comp = "";
while(strlen($comp) <= $cpsz){
/*$cpsz is the compressed size*/
$comp .= fread($fh, 1);
}
header("Accept-Ranges:bytes");
header("Connection: Keep-Alive");
header("Content-Type:audio/mpeg");
header("Content-Length:" . $ucps);
header("Content-Range:bytes 0-" . ($ucps-1) . "/" . $ucps);
header("ETag: xyz");
http_response_code (206);
$file = gzinflate($comp);
echo $file;
```

Is there anyway to make this more efficient than reading one byte at a time?

Comment: Using that concatenation is going to make the process really slow, as is calling strlen() every iteration. Why aren't you simply reading $cpsz bytes of data in one go via gzread() rather than 1 byte at a time?

Comment: Can you do that with fopen?